# How to Hide a title if one custom field is empty

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using advanced custom fields to show complementary products on widget. I add title before complementary products. I want to hide that title when acf field is empty. How can I do it? field name is:tamamlayici_urun_1_gorseli

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code I hope it will work. When this field empty then
Example:

```
<?php if( get_field('tamamlayici_urun_1_gorseli') ): ?>
    <p> Title Show </p>
    <p>Field Value: <?php the_field('tamamlayici_urun_1_gorseli'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```